# Analysis of a circuit with transformer, R and C components

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors, transformer

[image]

I am not able to solve the above problem. I don't think my equations are wrong but I am not able to solve them. Please help me with this.

The answer given in my workbook is 3.93cost(3t+59.9)

Method A

[image]

Method B

[image]

This is not a homework problem. I was practicising problems when I came across this one.

Comment: Can you try KCL and KVL with a current source?

Comment: Can you please show some steps. I am not able to understand.

Comment: Start with Norton transform.

Comment: Again derivative term will cause problems. Please show the equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with Chu that you can save yourself some pain by using phasors/Fourier transform, it *is* possible to solve these equations.

$$\begin{align}
&v_x)\quad &\frac{v_s-v_x}{1} + \frac{v_1-v_x}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{d(v-v_x)}{dt} &= 0 \\
&v_1)\quad &\frac{v_x - v_1}{2} - i_1 &= 0 \\
&v)\quad &\frac{1}{3}\frac{d(v_x-v)}{dt} + i_2 - \frac{v}{5} &= 0\\
&tf)\quad &v &= 4v_1\\
& & i_1 &= 4i_2
\end{align}$$

You can eliminate \$\frac{1}{3}\frac{d(v-v_x)}{dt}\$ using the third equation by substituting it in the first equation.

$$\frac{1}{3}\frac{d(v-v_x)}{dt} = i_2 - \frac{v}{5}$$

You can then solve all equations but the third to all unknowns except \$v\$ to find that (I used a CAS like *Maxima* to solve it)

$$\begin{align}
i_1 &= \frac{20v_s-9v}{55} \\
i_2 &= \frac{20v_s-9v}{220} \\
v_1 &= \frac{v}{4} \\
v_x &= \frac{160v_s - 17v}{220}
\end{align}$$

which allows us to plug \$i_2\$ and \$v_x\$ back in:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}\frac{d(v-v_x)}{dt} &= i_2 - \frac{v}{5} \\
&\Downarrow \\
79\frac{dv}{dt} + 53v &= 80\cos(3t) - 640\sin(3t)
\end{align}$$

The homogeneous solution is not important, as we're only interested in the steady-state solution. The particular solution is given by

$$\begin{align}
v(t) &= \frac{77960}{29489}\cos(3t) -\frac{7480}{29489}\sin(3t) \\
&= 2.656\cos(3t + 5.48^\circ)
\end{align}$$

Now, I'm not sure how you would get the reference answer of your book. When I verified using LTSpice, it seemed to support this answer rather than the one from your book.

[image: Verification using LTSpice]

Comment: please check my answer and help me with the last step.

Comment: Also is it necessary to use that CAS Maxima thing. Can't it be done by hand ?

Comment: A CAS is not necessary. It's just faster. To avoid people asking what my intermediary steps are, I include the mention.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be doing a transient analysis; this problem calls for complex notation. Represent the capacitor's reactance as: \$\small -j\:X_C=-\large\frac{j}{\omega C}\small =-j\$, let the source voltage be: \$\small V_S=4+j0=4\$, and then use nodal analysis.

Comment: please check my answer and help me with the last step.

Answer (score 1):

I calculated v using phasor analysis using y-parameter. Please help me in how to write time domain representation of v.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is correct too. The final cosine would have an amplitude of \$0.664\cdot 4 = 2.656\$, and the phase shift is \$5.48^\circ\$, so you get \$2.656\cdot \cos(3t + 5.48^\circ)\$.